# $E/F$ is a finite Galois extension. Let $b\in E$, and $b_1=b, b_2...$ are the orbit of b under the action

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $E/F$ be a finite Galois extension.  So $E=F(a)$.  Let $b\in E$, and let $b_1=b, b_2,...,b_n$ be the orbit of $b$ under the action of the Galois group $G$.

(a)Show that the minimal polynomial of $b$ is given by $f(x)=\Pi(x-b_j)$.

(b)Show that $E=F(b)$ if and only if $n=|G|$ (that is, no two elements of $G$ send $b$ to the same image).

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) The coefficients of $f$ are clearly Galois-invariant (since $G$ just permutes the factors), so $f$ lives in $F[x]$, and the minimal polynomial divides $f$; it equals $f$ because no other sub-product of $\prod (x - b_j)$ is Galois-invariant.

(b) Note that $(1, b, b^2, \dots, b^{n-1})$ forms a basis of $F(b)$ over $F$. If $n = |G|$, then since $E/F$ is Galois, we have $n = [E : F]$. Thus, $[F(b) : F] = n = [E : F]$, implying $F(b) = E$.